# Регулярное выражение в таблице

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как определить текст внутри первых двух ячеек строки у таблицы? Пытался через регулярные выражения `regV=/^\<td\>.+\<\/td\>/;`, но он выводит мне всю строку, а не `<td>Какой-то</td><td>текст</td>`. Посоветуйте также литературу по регулярным выражениям.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не тратьте в пустую время ( действительно верный RegExp получится очень сложным ):

```
var tr_td = document.getElementById('my_table').rows[0].children;
var td1 = tr_td[0].innerHTML;
var td2 = tr_td[1].innerHTML;
```

P.S: Под "действительно верный" я понимаю тот, который учитывает, что у `TD` могут быть атрибуты, что в строке может быть всего один `TD`, ......

Comment: timka_s, спасибо за совет. Он верный, но мне его пришлось вот так подкорректировать(аналог на jQuery): 
 `var tr_td = $(this).children();
 var td1 = tr_td[0].innerHTML;
 var td2 = tr_td[1].innerHTML;
 alert(td1+" "+td2);`

Answer (score 1):

Используйте группу, для этого служат скобки.

```
regV=/^\<td\>(.+)\<\/td\>/;
```

Было бы не плохо указать, в каком языке программирования вы используйте регулярные выражения.

Comment: Пишу на jQuery. Shurik, спасибо за совет, но он почему-то вывел мне почти то же самое но через запятую. Не могу заставить его вывести только первые два <td>...</td>

Answer (score 0):

`regV=/^\<td?\>?.*?\<\/td\>?\<td?\>?.*?\<\/td\>?/` - Вот то что я искал.
Осталось только убрать лишние `<tr>` и `</tr>`. Делается это так. Например

```
c="<td>Кусаинова</td><td>Асель</td>"
var x=c.replace(/\<\/td\>\<td\>/," ");
x=x.replace(/\<\/td\>/,"");
x=x.replace(/\<td\>/,"");
```

Получим `Кусаинова Асель`.
Почему-то в `IEv6` не сработал. Наверное не понимает регулярные выражения.

Comment: @Light Yagami, поправьте свой ответ, и мы отметим вопрос как отвеченный.